# Update a column based on other rows column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table t which looks like this

```
   key fill store end_date    status
    1  123  1      2019-04-30  0  
    2  1234 1      2019-04-30  0
    3  123  1      2019-05-01  0
```

Now I need to update the first record and set `status=1` as the third record has same fill, store value and it is latest.

Output:

```
   key fill store end_date    status
    1  123  1      2019-04-30  1  
    2  1234 1      2019-04-30  0
    3  123  1      2019-05-01  0
```

I tried calculating `row_number` and tried to update the column based on it but unable to figure out how to use the result in the update clause.

```
update t set
  status = 1
from (
  select *
  from (
    select *
      , row_number() over (partition by fill, store order by end_dt desc) as row_num from t
    ) a
    where row_num = 2
  ) b
```

This query is updating all the records, what should change in my query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
with cte as (
    select status, row_number() over(partition by fill, store order by end_date desc) rn
    from t
)
update cte set status = 1 where rn > 1
```

In the common table expression, `row_number()` ranks records having the same `fill` and `store` by descending `end_date`. Then, the outer query sets `status` to `1` on rows that were not ranked first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a correlated subquery:

```
update my_table a
set status = 1
where exists (
  select 1 
  from my_table b 
  where b.fill = a.fill 
    and b.store = a.store 
    and b.end_date > a.end_date
)
```